# iOS - Operating text input as code

Tags: ios, objective-c, lua

Is it possible to have input from a `UITextField` operated as code? for instance, I have a text field and button. The user enters some code (for instance `NSLog(@"hello world")`) then presses the button. Whatever the user inputted is treated as code and is operated as though part of the usual .m file.

So, is this possible?

(Edit: A little bit like Python's input command, where input can be treated as code

If you need any more information just ask, though I think that should cover it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically speaking: yes, it's possible. But it's far from easy.

So what you want is: entering some Objective-C code and make it run, from within the app. What is needed for this is:

1. An Objective-C compiler embedded in the app;
2. And the permission of the OS/kernel to run the resulting code.

The solution to problem #1 may be embedding the Clang/LLVM compiler suite in your app (but it's huge, several tens of megabytes). However, 1. be prepared for not being able to port it to iOS (it is **hard** to port a functional cross-toolchain, especially with the brainless build system of LLVM and Clang), 2. and the generated code won't be codesigned anyway, so it won't run in an official environment, it would only run on jailbroken devices.

---

If you want to provide some kind of interactive programming feature to the user, you better try embedding a small scripting language such as [Lua](http://lua.org) into your app instead.

Comment: I second your suggestion for embedding Lua. It's small and designed for easy embedding.

Comment: @MikeC. That's how the creator of Codea became a millionaire... :P

Comment: Thanks! Marked as answer & +1.

Comment: Ah, just realised I can't +1 on this account as I don't have enough reputation. Sorry. Marked as answer though,

Answer (score 0):

Short and practical answer, no.

Python is an interpreted language, objective-c needs to be compiled first in order to run and you don't have a compiler available inside an app. Even if you had a compiler, that code wouldn't be able to run (it's not signed) and you would probably be breaking lots of appstore rules.

Comment: Please, tell me what's wrong with the answer and I will edit it. I was trying to give a more concise and easy answer than yours (which is more accurate but maybe too difficult).

Comment: "Short answer, no." - this is false.

Comment: Ok, now I state it's short and practical (it's both). I do not state it's 100% true and accurate. Thanks for your insight.